# Need help to fetch data from database in php codeigntier

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to build a project in php codeigniter. But I'm stuck to fetch data from database.

I'm using mysql, codeigniter-3.1.10 & php-7.0.33.

Database config file:

```
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '221b',
    'database' => 'car',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

My model is

```
if (defined('BASEPATH') OR exit ('No direct script access allowed'));
    class Homepage_model extends CI_Model{
        public $result;
        public $rs;

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();

        }

        public function get_data($slug = FALSE){
            if ($slug === FALSE) {
                $query = $this->db->get('cars');
                return $query->result_array();
            }

            $query = $this->db->get_where('cars', array('status' => "Available"));
            return $query->row_array();
        }
    }
```

In model file I want to fetch all data from the table cars when the value of database field "status" is 'Available'.
Controller file:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Homepage extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->load->model('Homepage_model');
        $rs = $this->Homepage_model->get_data();
        $this->load->view('homepage_view', $rs);

    }
}
```

and my view portion where I'm going to show the data is:

```
                foreach($rs as $rws){
                    //echo $rws['car_id'];

            ?>
                <li>
                    <?php echo $rws['car_id'];?>
                    <a href="book_car.php?id=<?php echo $rws['car_id'] ?>">
                        <img class="thumb" src="cars/<?php echo $rws['image'];?>" width="300" height="200">
                    </a>
                    <span class="price"><?php echo 'Kshs.'.$rws['hire_cost'];?></span>
                    <div class="property_details">
                        <h1>
                            <a href="book_car.php?id=<?php echo $rws['car_id'] ?>"><?php echo 'Car Make>'.$rws['car_type'];?></a>
                        </h1>
                        <h2>Car Name/Model: <span class="property_size"><?php echo $rws['car_name'];?></span></h2>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
```

I've done this. But when I browse the webpage none of this data is show.Please help to solve this.

Comment: in `get_data` you are not passing `slug` param, so second result will return and that result is an `row_`array` so you cant use it in `foreach` so return `result_array()` instead of `row_array()`

Comment: I've changed the row_array() as result_array(), but nothing happened.

Comment: print the response r u getting data or not from DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your Controller Function
pass `$data` Variable like  `$this->load->view('homepage_view', $data);`

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('Homepage_model');
    $result = $this->Homepage_model->get_data();
    $data['rs'] =  $result; 
    $this->load->view('homepage_view', $data);
}
```

Comment: Now the $rs variable will be available on view file

Answer (score 0):

Here is changed in query

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('cars', array('status' => "Available"))->result_array();
return $query;
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Model**

```
public function get_data($slug = FALSE){
    if ($slug === FALSE) {
        $query = $this->db->get('cars');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('cars', array('status' => "Available"));
    $result = $query->result_array(); # change
    return $result; # change
}
```

**In Controller**

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('Homepage_model');
    $result = $this->Homepage_model->get_data();
    $data['rs'] =  $result; # or  $data['rs']  = $this->Homepage_model->get_data(); assign directly 
    $this->load->view('homepage_view', $rs);
}
```

And **In View** `foreach($rs as $rws){` will works

Make sure the table is not empty.

Comment: in controller if I write this
```$this->load->view('homepage_view', $rs);```
this gives me an error "Undefined variable: rs"
and if I write this
```$this->load->view('homepage_view', $data['rs']);```
this is shown nothing.

Comment: @Sharif use as i posted `$result = $this->Homepage_model->get_data(); $data['rs'] =  $result;`

Comment: I did as you said. But this happens "Message: Undefined variable: rs"

Comment: Abdulla, please try to refrain from using quote/citation formatting, unless the material you are presenting is a quote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just change `$row_array()` with `$result_array()`

```
return $this->db->get_where('cars', array('status' => "Available"))->result_array();
```

`row_array()` is used to fetch only one while `$result_array()` all records in the form of an associative array

Read more about [row array](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-rows) and [result array](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-arrays)